# How to prevent the duplication in one-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I have 2 `tables` named `Company` and `Customer`. **One-to-Many relationship**, *where a company can have many customers and a customer belongs to this company.*

```
Company Table                    Customers Table  
Company Id,                       Customer_ID,    
Company Name,                     Customer_Name,
Company Address                   Phone_no.
```

In the seeder,

```
factory(App\Company::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($data) {
            $customers= factory(App\Customer::class, 5)->make();
            $data->customers()->saveMany($customers);

          });
```

so, each company generates 5 customers each.

The Idea is

```
company_id         customerId
 1,1,1,1,1         1,2,3,4,5 // the customerId should not be repeated again like 1,2,2,3,4,
 2,2,2,2,2         2,3,6,7,8 // should not be 2,3,3,3,6
 3,3,3,3,3         5,7,8,9,2 and so on
```

`A company can have many customers but not the customer's with the sameId.`
How to avoid the duplication for the customerID using php?, and a condition to check if the company has already the customer with the SameId, then remove them from the customer?
Could anyone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: store data like this in a single row `1,2,3,4,5` is not a good idea for SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
factory(Company::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($company){
        $company->customers()
            ->createMany(factory(Customer::class, 5)->make()->map->getAttributes());
    });
```

Comment: It's not working! CustomerID's were again repeated.

Comment: Oh, you need to add one to many relation between the tables. 
you just need to follow the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
and it will work.
if you stuck I'm here to help

Comment: you need also to add company_id column in customers table

Comment: Yes added, Is there anyways to check and stop the duplication of CustomerID for the particular company_ID ? Can It be included inside the seeder?

Comment: yes, the one that I provided you with :'D, did you add the customers method in the company model and it still not working?

Comment: Yes, added the customers() in the company model. But still not working:-(

Comment: I'm sorry but could you provide me with the customers method code?

Comment: This is the Customer() code : public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }

Comment: it should be 

`customers() { return $this->hasMany(Customer::class, 'company_id', 'id'); }`

or just leave it for laravel to figure it out 
like so 

`customers() { return $this->hasMany(Customer::class); }`

try that and let's see how it goes